# Using Multiple Serial Ports with arduino nano

Tags: serial, xbee, gps

I am using a arduino nano to control a adafruit ultimate gps and a xbee wireless controller. However I recently ran into a problem using both at the same time (before I was using each separately until now) and read that I cannot listen to 2 software serials at the same time with a arduino. The biggest problem I see is that since I can only listen to one at a time, if I open a port, will cached data from the xbee and/or gps instantly start transferring in? Or or it more luck based that I will catch it as it comes? How should I go about coding around this? Should I just close and reopen the ports as needed(assuming there is no luck factor involved)? Any help is greatly appreciated. I will explain more if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SoftwareSerial](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) library in order to instantiate a second (soft) serial port.

By looking at the [example](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial#Example), it seems that you can use any two digital pins to use SoftwareSerial library and instantiate a second serial port along with the hardware serial port.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the GPS's EN pin to enable and disable the communication to it, and also try to use the RTS/CTS pins of the XBee to control the flow, since that's their actual purpose there :)

I hope that helped.

Comment: The EN pin might shut it down and then you'll have to reconnect to sattelites?

You could however, use a transistor on the dataline so you can toggle the stream of data coming in.

Answer (score 0):

The Mega and the Due have 4 UARTs. It seems like those should work, but they are much larger. I'm embarking on a project that needs to be small and use two serial ports. I'm looking at the Teensy, which has three UARTs.